# 301 redirect - Redirect parent but not it's children

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How would I go about re-directing a parent directory but not children? See my specific issue below. All and any help is appreciated!

**Parent** -

```
redirect 301 /community/whats-happening http://www.stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/
```

- redirects parent directory

**Child** -

```
redirect 301 /community/whats-happening/celebrating-halloween-stapleton http://www.stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/celebrating-halloween-in-stapleton/
```

- redirects incorrectly to http://www.stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/celebrating-halloween-stapleton

**I have tried a handful of other options to no success. See below:**

```
RewriteRule  ^community/whats-happening/. /whats-happening/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^community/whats-happening/(.*)$ /whats-happening/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?community/whats-happening/?$ http://www.stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/ [R=301]

RewriteRule ^community/whats-happening/(.*) http://stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^community/whats-happening/(.*)/(.*)/? http://stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because of your first redirect. The `Redirect` directive redirects all subdirectories and files to, so:

```
Redirect 301 /abcd http://domain.com/xyz
```

means

- `/abcd/` -> `http://domain.com/xyz/`
- and `/abcd/1234/` -> `http://domain.com/xyz/1234/`
- and `/abcd/1234/z.html` -> `http://domain.com/xyz/1234/z.html`

etc.

If you only want the parent directory to redirect, use a regex and `RedirectMatch` with a `$` end character:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/community/whats-happening/?$ http://www.stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/  
RedirectMatch 301 ^/community/whats-happening/celebrating-halloween-stapleton/?$ http://www.stapletondenver.com/whats-happening/celebrating-halloween-in-stapleton/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, that works great! Redirects always get me with all the variations out there. Learned a lot here, thanks again!