# 301 redirect - Redirect parent but not for its children. For IIS version 10 Windows 2019

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, http-redirect

I am trying to figure out how to make sure the 301 redirect will work only on the parent and its children.
The children should have the same URLs.

Here is the code in the web.config:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Change of my parent page" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^my_old_parent$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/New-Parent-Page/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I tried different variations and nothing worked.
I looked at this thread:
[301 redirect - Redirect parent but not it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851475/301-redirect-redirect-parent-but-not-its-children)

They mentioned to use RedirectMatch instead of Redirect and it did not work for IIS.

I appreciate an idea of which code to use for IIS 10.

Thanks,

Doron

### Here is an update:

Hi Samwu,

See additional example:

```
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/Page-1
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/Page-2
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/Page-3
```

I want to change only the parent page as follows:

```
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com/New_Great_Page/
```

All other pages below the above new URL stay the same.
That means all pages below will keep their URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/Page-1/
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/Page-2/
https://www.example.com/my_current_page/Page-3/
```

Thanks,

Doron

Comment: IIS was designed in a completely different way, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis So "the parent and its children" part doesn't apply. You have to dump those Apache stuffs and focus on learning new things, starting from how to write the proper regular expression.

Comment: You can try to use failed request tracking to view detailed request information, this can help you to identify the problem, or you can also give an example of your problem, I will make demo for you.

Comment: Hello,

I had to change the top URL to a different URL in the menu.
All URls below the top URL,need to stay the same.

I thought I provided enough explanation above.
Redirect 301 did not do the trick for me so far.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I mean from which url do you want to redirect to which url please give an example so I can make a demo for you.

Comment: Hi Samwu,

I added more samples URLs as what I need and see the top message. Thanks Doron

Comment: Hi Samwu,

It looks promising. Let me test that and will get back to you.

Thanks,

Doron

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^my_current_page(.*)$" />
     <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/New_Great_Page/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```